# failed to resolve

Tags: android, gradle

when i want to build the project it give me the field to resolve some repo like

Failed to resolve: multidex
Open File

Failed to resolve: espresso-core
Open File

Failed to resolve: runner
Open File

Failed to resolve: multidex-instrumentation
Open File

Failed to resolve: monitor
Open File

Failed to resolve: support-annotations
Open File

Failed to resolve: espresso-idling-resource
Open File

and this is my gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        // google() //added this
        jcenter()
        google()
        // google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
//mavenCentral()
        //google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.radon.timceshop"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
/*
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2(1).jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.11.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
*/


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


   // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.3'




    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    //implementation files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
   // implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native'




    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    //implementation files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2(1).jar')

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'


    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    // implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
   // compile 'ir.huri:JalaliCalendar:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
/*
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    //implementation files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2(1).jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'


    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    // implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'*/

}
```

Comment: can you share the gradle file for the app?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing some dependencies. You should try adding them like

`// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.espresso/espresso-core
compile group: 'androidx.test.espresso', name: 'espresso-core', version: '3.1.0-alpha1'`

Do this for all missing dependencies. 
You can find both Maven and Gradle dependencies on [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/)